# convert generic list to datatable using linq..?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

```
List<Employee> objEmpList = new List<Employee>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    { 
        objEmpList.Add(new Employee(){ID=i, Name="aa" + i});
    }
```

I want to create table with generic list items as rows using linq or lambda expressions...How to do that..??I did that using loops but I want do that using linq..!

Comment: Did what using loops? You didn't do anything using loops that was an attempt to what you want to do?

Answer (score 9):

Use [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx) extension. See msdn article [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

```
DataTable table = objEmpList.CopyToDataTable();
```

BTW here is simpler way to create list of employees:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,5)
          .Select(i => new Employee { ID = i, Name = "aa" + i })
          .ToList();
```

Consider also using [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/):

```
Builder<Employee>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build()
```

Comment: @EliGassert yep, especially when you working with databables - you even don't need to write any object shredders

Comment: Yes, with the assumption that `Employee` is a `DataRow`. Or maybe I don't anderstand the sentence in question. He want to create firstly rows from list of objects or these objects are data rows.

Comment: @yBee nope, see the linked article which shows how custom `CopyToDataTable<T>` extension method implemented